# Angular 2 - PrimeNG - dataTable Expand one row at a time

Tags: angular, grid, expandablelistview, primeng

In PrimeNG - is there any Way to allow only one row to be expanded at a time ?

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" expandableRows="true">
        <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
         <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
        <ng-template let-car pTemplate="rowexpansion">
         ...
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Could you provide more information, please?

Comment: in primeNg, if you configured your datatable to be expandable, there is an Icon on the left of each row and when you click on it the row is expanded for more details about the row.
I would like that only one row will be expanded at a time.

Comment: @haseoh, thanks for the comment. i updated the question. I'm talking about row, not group.

Comment: There's not much about the expandable rows in documentation, but I found 4 events that are fired on expand and collapse: `onRowExpand`, `onRowCollapse`, `onRowGroupExpand` and `onRowGroupCollapse`. I suppose we could make it happen as you want it to. If I'll do a working solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: I did for rowSelect event - when the user is clicking on the row.
but was not able to do the same when the user clicks on the expand icon on the left side of the row. I need both events to do the same action - select the row and open the details panel inside. when there is another click on the row, or on the expand icon on a selected row the row should become unselected.

Comment: I'm preety sure `onRowSelect` fires when you enable `SelectionMode`. You could work around it. When you select one row and then select other row, the 1st one is deselected with `onRowUnselect`. Maybe you could collapse the expanded row with `onRowUnselect` event. I tried to do it, but I miserably failed to do so :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152239/discussion-between-john-smith-and-haseoh).

Comment: I found something that could help you, but I can't test it since I'm writing this on my phone. In DataTable documentation, there is `rowExpandMode` method with default value set to `multiple`, you can change it to `single` to propably expand only one row at a time.

Comment: @Haseoh works perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I upgraded PrimeNG Grid to TurboTable vesion..
it's new since PrimeNG 5.
instead of using

Answer (score 10):

Just try to use below `<p-dataTable [value]="cars" rowExpandMode="single" expandableRows="true">`

Add rowExpandMode="single" to open one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> I can give you clue how to solve it and hope it will work for you.

```
It is not the actual solution for this issue but you will get Idea how to 
solve this. Also I am using javascript in the code. You can convert it into 
angular way.
```

```html
<p-dataTable expandableRows="true"
   (onRowExpand) = "onRowExpand($event)">
```

```js
onRowExpand(data : any) {
        var d = document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-fw ui-c ui-row-toggler fa-chevron-circle-down');
        if (d.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                this.renderer.setElementStyle(d[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling,'display','none')
            }
        }
}
```

```
What i am doing here is fetching the class which is having 
fa-chevron-circle-down'. Then taking parent element recursively till the 
<tr>. Then take the next sibling element and you can delete it or you can do 
display none dynamically.
```

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG 7.1.1: set `rowExpandMode` attribute to 'single' will works.

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="tableData" [rows]="pageOptions.perPage" [totalRecords]="totalRecords"[rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPageOptions" [responsive]="true" rowExpandMode="single">
```